# how can i add a word in a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, authentication

So i'm trying to make a login and register program in Python i already made the register part, but now i'm struggling with the login part.
and a self made simple database, using classes to store the data.
there are two files:
one for database and register and login program and the register and login program reads database.

This is the current login code:

```
username = input("Enter your username: ")
if username == "(acc_info." + username + ".username)":
    print("Valid username")
```

But it didn't work of course

and `acc.info` is the data base

This is the database

```
class Accounts:
    def __init__(self, username, pw, is_admin):
        self.username = username
        self.pw = pw
        self.is_admin = is_admin

    def full_info(self):
        return '{} {} {}'.format(self.username, self.pw, self.is_admin)

admin = Accounts('admin', '5555', True)
```

I was expecting the input called `username` gets a username like `admin` and when i press enter it runs `(acc_info.admin.username)` and the output would be `admin` and if the input is same as the output it would send me to the next part which is passwords but if i know how to do the username i can do the password part too.

but now the output is `(acc.info.admin.username)`
and the program checks if the input (which is `admin`) is the same as  `(acc.info.admin.username)`. and it doesnt work because the output `(acc.info.admin.username)` should run and give me a output of `admin`

Comment: I don't know if this is a language barrier issue, but this is just a jumble of words. I can't understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: Yeah i dont know, im a starter in python so im not really sure how to explain a problem in python

Comment: It's not about being a beginner in Python or not. I was too, a few years ago, and I can sympathise with that. That doesn't stop you conveying the issue in coherent sentences, though.

Comment: In any case, I assume you're using a web framework such as Django or Flask?

Comment: No, I'm using PyCharm not a web framework, to run my codes instantly and see if they work properly

Comment: Strings are not automatically executed as if they're code. Creating a string like `(acc_info.admin.username)` does not try to access that variable, it's just text.

Comment: You should write functions that take parameters. So you'd write something like `if get_acc_info(username, 'admin')`

Comment: how should that function exactly work? (sorry im not really good at this)

Comment: i did, but i still have no idea how to do it, i'm searching for this for almost a month but i still cant find any answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The check `if username == "(acc_info." + username + ".username)"` is never going to pass.  This is asking if the string entered by the user is the same string you get when you concatenate "(acc_info.", what the user entered, and ".username)".  So if the user types in "`bob`" for example, it compares the strings "bob" and "(acc_info.bob.username)".  Those two strings are obviously different.

It's not entirely clear to me how your "database" and "(acc_info ..." is supposed to fit into what you're trying to do.  But here's a working example of doing some login and checks:

```
class Accounts:
    def __init__(self, username, pw, is_admin):
        self.username = username
        self.pw = pw
        self.is_admin = is_admin

    def full_info(self):
        return '{} {} {}'.format(self.username, self.pw, self.is_admin)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self.username == other.username and self.pw == other.pw)

def check_account(entered, account_list):
    for account in account_list:
        if entered == account:
            return account
    return False


accounts = [ Accounts('admin', '5555', True),
             Accounts('bob', '1234', False),
             Accounts('jill', '4321', False),
             Accounts('hacker', '123', False)]

entered_username = input("Enter your username: ")
entered_password = input("and your password: ")

entered_account = Accounts(entered_username, entered_password, None)

matched_account = check_account(entered_account, accounts)

if matched_account:
    print("Welcome, %s" % matched_account.username)
    if matched_account.is_admin:
        print("And I see you're an actual admin! Wow!")
else:
    print("Invalid username/password.")
```

Granted, this isn't the complete sort of approach I'd use in real life (e.g., some of these steps are not only insecure but not the most memory-efficient).  But again, it's at least something that seems to fit what you're asking for.